# Get the specific portion of the HTML Page using IPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my app, i have a URL of some webpage & i want to get only specific part/portion from that URL(its html page) by identifying the html tags.

for example, i want to get portion as `<div id="content"> to </div>` as per html source code.
so that i can save it on another file.

**e.g. my urls are**

**1)** http://www.makepartsfast.com/2012/09/4337/more-3d-printing-in-metals-ex-one-introduces-the-m-flex-3d-printing-system/

**2)** http://www.windpowerengineering.com/policy/new-study-shows-the-benefits-of-wind-energy-in-kansas/

**3)** http://www.windpowerengineering.com/design/mechanical/bearings/podcast-for-windtech-2012-generator-maintenance/

All of these URLs opens the article html page. But i want to show only the **main content of the HTML page**.

I also successful by my following code for some URL only.

**My code:**

```
NSString *originalString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.windpowerengineering.com/uncategorized/how-superfinishing-boosts-component-reliability/"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSString *extractedString = nil;


    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<div id=\"content\">" intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanString:@"<div id=\"content\">" intoString:nil];



    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<div style=\"clear:both;\">" intoString:&extractedString];


    if (extractedString) 
    {
        // string was extracted
        NSLog(@"%@", extractedString);
    }
```

But different page may have more than one  `<div style=\"clear:both;\">` tag. So when the method encounter that tag it shows me only show the content till that tag.

**Suggestion** Now, I think to count the all the `<div>` tags and try to get all the main content from that HTML page.But I am confused to do this.

How can i do it?

Help me!!

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used AFFeedParsing Method. Because all articles are feeds. you find sample code on

1. [cocoacontrols](http://cocoacontrols.com)